# SwipeRefreshLayout disable a webview inner content from scroll up

Tags: android, xamarin, webview, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin Android Webview inside a Swiperefreshlayout (which i use it in order to reload the webview content)  as shown below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
      <EditText
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/txtURL" />
      <LinearLayout
          android:orientation="horizontal"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
       <Button
            android:text="Go"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/btnGO"
            android:layout_weight="2" />
        <Button
            android:text="Forward"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/btnForward"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
      </LinearLayout>
      <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
          android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.webkit.WebView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:id="@+id/webView" />
      </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
```

The problem: I have some tables inside the webview  Whenever I scroll the content of the table dawn fast, I cant scroll it back up .. when I do that the refresh icon appears from behind the toolbar and reload the page.
Any suggestion?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3jmc.png)

Comment: What's the page like in the webview? I have tested your code and it works fine with other pages. It would not refresh when I soroll the page.

Comment: I add an image pointed to the inner scroll that i can scroll it down but when i scroll pack up the  SwipeRefreshLayout works so i cant't scroll up the items .